# Client misspells name in email conversation

Tags: email, freelancing, clients

I am freelancing right now and I have a client who misspells my name every time in email conversation. The conversation goes something like this:

```
Hi smash

We would..

Thanks
```

In the first couple of emails I didn't raise any issue because it could be that he was in a hurry and misspelled it by mistake. But the last time he used the word 'smash' to address me which I don't like at all.
Is there a way to address this issue in a polite manner?

Comment: Do you have reason to think the client disrespects you or does this on purpose? Could it be autocorrect? Could the client think it's funny? Do you only email with this client, are there phone calls once in a while?

Comment: @mart I have a feeling the client thinks it is funny but I don't think he means to disrespect me. And I meet him from time to time but no phone calls.
DavidK This issue is different.

Comment: @shash7 How will answers for your question be any different?

Comment: Sometimes I misspell my *own name* in emails that go out to clients.  It's a product of typing too fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But the last time he used the word 'smash' to address me which I don't
>   like at all. Is there a way to address this issue in a polite manner?

Having a client misspell your name shouldn't be a huge deal for a freelancer. Many of us have names that are frequently misspelled or mispronounced. Most folks would just ignore it and move on.

However, if it bothers you enough, you can gently correct the client in person or on the phone.

The next time your client says "Hi, Smash.", you simply say (in a pleasant tone)  "It's Shash. Hi, how are you today?"

Make sure your name is in all your emails.

Either the client will eventually start to remember, or you'll need to decide what to do about a client who simply cannot get your name right.

Comment: Sounds good but in all emails I always have my full name which should be enough. In the next email conversation I will tell him to pronounce my name correctly.

Comment: keywords: in person or on the phone. don't trust this to written communication, it's terrible easy to come across wrong in writing. Seriously, don't do this by mail. Find an excuse to call him (som clarification or other) and tell him politely if your next  meeting is not soon enough for you. It's really easy to come across wrong in writing

Comment: @mart fair enough. I will ring him tomorrow.

Comment: @shash7 Some email clients even auto-hide the signature line where you write your name, so if that's the case they wouldn't even have had the opportunity to read your sig line without deactivating that feature. E.g. Google's gmail client does this by default until you click on a small button where the signature would normally appear. Don't like that feature.

Comment: Just an update, I phoned the client and told that that there is a problem wit h the spelling, its shash, not smash. He told me that's because the autocorrect feature(possibly on his iphone) did that and he will spell it correctly next time.